# I refused to open sop: links in Sopcast. Is there anyway to reset it?

Tags: google-chrome

`sop://` links are trying to open in the browser (Chrome), so I have to copy the link. Is there any way to edit which program opens these links or initiate the "do you wish to open with Sopcast" message in Chrome? I just can't find this setting.

I want to change the current behaviour so that Chrome does what I want when I click `sop://` links.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10, you can change the default protocol by:

1. Open Settings -> Apps
2. On the left pane select Default apps.
3. On the right pane, scroll down and select "Choose default apps by protocol".
4. Look for the protocol on the list, then click on the current default app (in your case Google Chrome)S select another app among the list of apps to set it as the new default app to open the protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unfortunately there is no SOPCAST protocol there.

Answer (score 0):

If none of your protocol handlers work, try turning them on in Chrome.

1. Click the More Actions ( ⋮ ) menu.
2. Click *Settings*.
3. Click *Privacy and security*.
4. Click *Site Settings*.
5. Click *Additional permissions*.
6. Click *Handlers*.
7. Click the switch next to *Do not allow any site to handle protocols*.

[image: Turning on handlers in Chrome]

If you only need to change a single handler, look for the protocol handler icon on the right side of the address bar:

[image: Protocol handler setting]

Click on the icon and select "Allow" or "Manage". Generally, any handler that has been blocked should appear in the *Handlers* settings window as shown below:

[image: Blocked protocol handler]

Comment: First of all thank you for your time for such a detailed answer. I have had this option enabled long time ago. Still not working. I'm looking somewhere there should be a setting that tells Chrome when clicking on sopcast:// ask to open in external app or not. I said not, how can I revert that ?

Comment: @Undry From everything I can see, if you blocked the protocol handler *in Chrome*, it should show up in the handlers list as "blocked". I've added a bit more information to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time again, but no there are only email ones that are blocked. I know it's really a minor issue, sopcast is not popular anymore, it's just funny that you can't change it anywhere in settings.

Comment: @Undry Can you try opening a new Chrome profile (as Guest, for example) to see if that works? It's pretty strange that you can't change it.

Comment: Mmm afraid to lose my fragile peace with google, but will try.

Comment: As a last-ditch effort, try following [these instructions](https://www.alexander-fuchs.net/reset-protocol-handler-in-chrome/).

Comment: Thank's I will just give up. Searched the folder too many cache entries. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Open the following URL:

```
chrome://settings/handlers
```

See if it is there so you can reset/change it.

If it is not there try this:

1. Close chrome and kill all processes that have to do with Chrome.
2. Go To `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`.
3. Open `Local State` in a text editor.
4. Search for `Protocol` or `SOP`.

If it's not there you can also search in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and open `Preferences` in a text editor. Search for `Protocol` or `SOP`

Another possibility:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLWhitelist]

"1"="sop://*"
```

or

```
"1"="sop:?*"
```